# Remove values from array inside a hash

Tags: perl

I have a hash `%m_h` with a couple of different data types inside. I want to remove the item `'q20_bases'` from the array in `$VAR4` but can't figure out how.

Data Structure (From `print Dumper %m_h`)

```
$VAR1 = 'run_m';
$VAR2 = [
          'run_id',
          'machine',
          'raw_clusters',
          'passed_filter_reads',
          'yield'
        ];
$VAR3 = 'ln_m';
$VAR4 = [
          'run_id',
          'lane_number',
          'read_number',
          'length',
          'passed_filter_reads',
          'percent_passed_filter_clusters',
          'q20_bases',
          'q30_bases',
          'yield',
          'raw_clusters',
          'raw_clusters_sd',
          'passed_filter_clusters_per_tile',
          'passed_filter_clusters_per_tile_sd',
          'percent_align',
          'percent_align_sd'
        ];
```

I tried `delete $m_h{'q20_bases'};` though it did nothing and I'm not sure what direction to head in.

Comment: Best to pass reference to Dumper for hashes and arrays (`print Dumper \%m_h`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[delete](http://p3rl.org/delete) removes a key and the associated value from a hash, not an element from an array.

You can use [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) to select the elements of the array that are different to `q20_bases`.

```
$m_h{ln_m} = [grep $_ ne 'q20_bases', @{ $m_h{ln_m} }];
```

or

```
@{ $m_h{ln_m} } = grep $_ ne 'q20_bases', @{ $m_h{ln_m} };
```

You can also use [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice) to remove an element from an array, but you need to know its index:

```
my ($i) = grep $m_h{ln_m}[$_] eq 'q20_bases', 0 .. $#{ $m_h{ln_m} };
splice @{ $m_h{ln_m} }, $i, 1;
```

You can see that you always need to dereference the value with `@{...}` to get the array from the array reference. Recent Perls also provide an alternative syntax for it:

```
$m_h{ln_m}->@*
```